# validar campo disabled

Tags: php, javascript

es posible identificar con javascripts cuando este campo esta selecionado y adicional este disabled y guardarlo en alguna variable?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para luego realizar alguna comparación y generar una alerta?

lo he intentado de esta forma

```
$('[type="submit"]#taller').click(function(){

        var hora_option = document.getElementById("form-field-hora");
        var hora_seleccionada = hora_option.options[hora_option.selectedIndex].text;

        if(horaInicial===hora_seleccionada){
            if ($('option[disabled]').val()){
                alert('Lo sentimos , la hora seleccionada ya fue agendada, por favor selecciona otra hora.');
                return true;
            }            
        }        
    })
```

pero no me funciona

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], ¿nos compartes que has intentado al momento?

Comment: $('[type="submit"]#taller').click(function(){

        var hora_option = document.getElementById("form-field-hora");
        var hora_seleccionada = hora_option.options[hora_option.selectedIndex].text;

        if(horaInicial===hora_seleccionada){
            if ($('option[disabled]').val()){
                alert('Lo sentimos , la hora seleccionada ya fue agendada, por favor selecciona otra hora.');
                return true;
            }            
        }        
    })

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y agrega el código o las explicaciones relevantes en la misma pregunta, no en comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, sí que es posible.

Al coger el selector *disabled* y hacer la comparativa en el *if* no lo haces correctamente. Te lo dejo hecho a continuación:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    var select = $('select');
    var option_disabled = select.children(':disabled');
    alert('la opción disabled es la '+option_disabled.text());
 });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3" disabled>3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="button" value="Buscar"/>
```